# Having problem while installing new packages on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, compression, rar

I am trying to install `unar` on CentOS 7 using `yum install epel-release` then `yum install unar` commands, but the result is:

```
  gnustep-base-libs-1.24.9-1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  trousers-0.3.14-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  avahi-libs-0.6.31-20.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  unar-1.10.1-1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  nettle-2.7.1-8.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  libobjc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  libxslt-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find plenty of answers around.  The issue is the Python upgrade.

This is because the system has been upgraded to python before, the original version is 2.7, after upgrading python3, yum calls python can not find the version of 2.7

There are two configuration files that need to be modified

```
/usr/bin/yum
/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down
```

Change the declaration path at the beginning of the file to the correct version and change back to the version of 2.7.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
```

The source of the original information is [ProgrammerSought](http://programmersought.com/article/44521860037/;jsessionid=F74598F6068F6B36E2B02592FB21AF2F).

Comment: It doesn't work, because  have no python2.7 and when I want to install it, it needs gcc! I had all of them and don't know why they lost all!

Comment: @Hasani well that could be the problem.  You have to know what you did with the OS so you can fix it.

Comment: I wanted to run a script that needed to python3, i tried to symlinking python3 to python and that problem soled but seems a new one happened!

Comment: @Hasani the python 2.7 and python3 are **not** compatible. You can't solve by symlinking (you should edit your question with any relevant information you did). You did not mention symlinking anywhere.